# Is ways or ways in which better?

Tags: word-choice

Which is preferred? More common?

> The ways I have learned to cope include...
>
> The ways in which I have learned to cope include...
>
> The ways I have learned to cope in include...

I hear the former almost exclusively, but I personally find it hard to say, as, in my mind, you do things "in a way", not "a way".

Comment: With the first sentence, the 'in which' is implied so it just gets dropped.

Comment: Does that mean "the ways I have learned to cope in" is wrong, or just not necessary?

Comment: You'd say something like: "The ways I have learned to cope include deep breating, drinking water, and getting enough sleep."

Comment: @EllaStrange, think of it this way. Rather than, in your mind, you "do things in a way," think of it as "the way you do things." Then the first sentence should make sense.

Comment: "the ways I have learned to cope in" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the first form you listed is most common. It can be interpreted as having the "in which" from the second form implicit. Alternatively, you can simply treat "ways" as a plural noun: the ways (strategies or patterns of behavior for achieving some goal) that the speaker learned (for the purpose of coping) are the items listed after "include...". Both interpretations are valid and give the same meaning.

The second form you gave ("The ways in which I have learned to cope include...") is also perfectly valid and again has the same meaning. The third form is not preferred, although it may be grammatically correct. If you feel very uncomfortable with the first form, it is fine to use the second, slightly more verbose phrasing.